# cannot ping from virtualbox ubuntu server

Tags: ping

I have this problem when I try to connect to the internet. The real problem is that I want to update my system, then I realized that I can't access the internet. I modified my resolv.conf file by putting the nameserver 8.8.8.8 but when pinging I still have the same error. I really need your help, I've been on it for days. I tried to apply what was given as resolution to a question similar to mine but it doesn't work.
I also point out that my ubuntu server is a virtual machine created on vurtualbox.
please help me please

Comment: Has this VM ever been able to connect to the Internet? What is the host OS? Have you confirmed that the network settings in VirtualBox are set to the correct mode and enabled? 

Comment: the VM has never connected to the internet.
the host operating system is windows 10.
to know if I have confirmed that VirtualBox network settings are set to the correct mode and enabled, you will need to tell me what to check please.
I am amateur with ubuntu.
i hope you would understand

Comment: Set your network settings (in VirtualBox) to “Bridged Mode”. That will allow the VM to get its own IP on your network. From there it can connect to the internet, and other devices on your network can connect to it.

Comment: thanks, it works